# To show function is not surjective

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

I am trouble understanding first three lines of proof . For onto we have to show that there exists some element in P(A) which doesnot have its preimage .But how did they have shown here

[image]

Comment: I believe you are misreading the text.  in the first paragraph following the word "Proof" the authors simply state what they intend to demonstrate.  As you have seen, there is nothing in that first paragraph that even hints at a proof...that must be coming up on the following page.

Comment: @lulu if consider A= {a,b} ,so P(A)={{a}.{b}.{a,b},{}} what is B here ?

Comment: @JPG Notice that B depends on the function g.

Comment: In their proof, $B$ depend on the map $g$ from $A$ to $\mathcal P(A)$. Wez can't say more,as we do not know $B$.

Comment: @JPG as Bernard says, the construction of B will depend on the supposed correspondence.  The rough logic of the proof will end up being this:  "we want to show there is no correspondence.  Well, suppose you had one.  We will then construct a few simple things based on it, things that you could certainly do if you really had a correspondence.  We will then show that these simple constructions lead to a logical contradiction, thereby showing that you didn't really have a correspondence."

Comment: @lulu hmm i see .i will rethink and write to you

Answer (score 1):

First three lines is restating what we have to show. The problem I see is notation because author uses same name $B$ for the set in $A$ and as an element in $P(A)$. We don't have surjectivity when we can find an element which doesn't have inverse. Author in the first three lines just says that he will construct this set/element in $P(A)$  and names it $B$.

Comment: $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is the set of all subsets of $A$, so $B \subset A \Leftrightarrow B \in \mathcal{P}(A)$.

Comment: @Strants I agree, but In the first case this is a subset, in the second case it's an element. In my opinion this notation might be confusing especially when you will have something like $B \in f(B)$